# Iterrate over values in a Pandas Series to replace a value if needed

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, series

I am trying to **iterate** through a **Pandas Series**.

If a value in the column **'% Renewable'** is greater than the **median** for the **'% Renewable'** column, the value should be assigned to **1** in a new column **'HighRenew'**. Otherwise the value should remain as it is.

The value of each item in the new series **'HighRenew'** should change according to whether the condition is met.

```
for value in Reducedset['% Renewable']: 
    if value >= Reducedset['% Renewable'].median():
       Reducedset['HighRenew'] = 1 
    else:
       Reducedset['HighRenew'] = value
```

However, I only want to amend the **specific value/element** in the series and not the entire series when the condition is met by the if loop.

*Could anybody give me any advice?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to create a new column (or modify an existing column) to get the value from another column if that value is less than the median or 1 if the value if greater or equal. It can be done simply:

```
Reducedset['HighRenew'] = Reducedset['% Renewable']
Reducetset.loc[Reducedset['% Renewable'] < Reducedset['% Renewable'].median(), 'HighRenew'] = 1
```

Alternatively you could use `np.where` to do that in one single pass:

```
Reducedset['HighRenew'] = np.where(Reducedset['% Renewable'] >= Reducedset['% Renewable'].median(),
                                   1, Reducedset['% Renewable'])
```

Comment: Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True) if I try to sort in ascending order like this,  and then view the series: Top15['HighRenew'], it does not appear in ascending order? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

You could use boolean variables instead.

```
median_value = Reducedset['% Renewable'].median()
Reducedset['% Renewable'][Reducedset['% Renewable'] > median_value] = 1
```

Comment: Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True) if I try to sort in ascending order like this, and then view the series: Top15['HighRenew'], it does not appear in ascending order? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```py
# The median can be calculated just once
median = Reducedset["% Renewable"].median()

for idx,row in Reducedset.iterrows():
    value = row["% Renewable"]
    if value >= median:
        df.iloc[idx,"% Renewable"] = 1
    # No need to re-assing the value if the condition is not met
```

I am assuming that `Reduceset` is your `pandas.dataframe`. Also, I am calculating the median before entering the loop, otherwise, the median will be changing every time the condition inside the loop is met.

Hope this helps, let me know how does it go! :D

Comment: Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True) if I try to sort in ascending order like this, and then view the series: Top15['HighRenew'], it does not appear in ascending order? Any ideas why? @Enriquebet

Comment: Can you add some examples of your ```dataframes```? so we can take a look. Without looking my first thought is that maybe is related to the ```data type``` of the column you want to sort, maybe you need to change it.

Comment: It will be best if you add it on your post

Comment: I have asked this question on a separate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802149/sorting-values-in-a-pandas-series-in-ascending-order-not-working-when-re-assigne?noredirect=1#comment109315637_61802149