# Sorting values in a pandas series in ascending order not working when re-assigned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, series

I am trying to sort a Pandas Series in ascending order.

```
Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Gives me:

```
Country
China                       1
Russian Federation          1
Canada                      1
Germany                     1
Italy                       1
Spain                       1
Brazil                      1
South Korea           2.27935
Iran                  5.70772
Japan                 10.2328
United Kingdom        10.6005
United States          11.571
Australia             11.8108
India                 14.9691
France                17.0203
Name: HighRenew, dtype: object
```

The values are in **ascending order**.

However, when I then modify the series in the **context of the dataframe**:

```
Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True)
Top15['HighRenew']
```

Gives me:

```
Country
China                       1
United States          11.571
Japan                 10.2328
United Kingdom        10.6005
Russian Federation          1
Canada                      1
Germany                     1
India                 14.9691
France                17.0203
South Korea           2.27935
Italy                       1
Spain                       1
Iran                  5.70772
Australia             11.8108
Brazil                      1
Name: HighRenew, dtype: object
```

Why this is giving me a different output to that above?

Would be grateful for any advice?

Comment: try `Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True).to_numpy()` or `Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)` when you sort_values  , the indexes dont change so it is aligning per the index

Comment: @anky thanks that works!!

Comment: @anky I think this would be a good answer to add

Comment: @Datanovice agreed!!

Comment: @Datanovice thanks, I was in search of a dupe after commenting, thought this might have been asked, nevertheless OP has answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True).to_numpy()
```

or

```
Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['HighRenew'].sort_values(ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

When you sort_values , the **indexes don't change** so it is aligning per the index!

Thank you to anky for providing me with this fantastic solution!